# Questions about Inverse trigonometry functions

Tags: trigonometry

[image: Questions]

Please note question number 3 has summation from $1$ to $2n$.

This is what I tried for question number $2$. 
If I put $n=1$ , the summation for two $\arcsin = \pi$. This can only happen if both $\arcsin=\pi/2$  $\implies$  $ x_1 = x_2 =1$. Which would mean summation of $x$ from $1$ to $2n$ should be equal to $2n$. The answer given is $0$. Where am I wrong?

I couldn't understand where to start question 3 and 4. Some hints would go a long way. Thanks.

Comment: You are not wrong. Since $\sin^{-1}x\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$, the sum in 2. and 3. equals $n\pi$ iff all sumands are equal $\frac{\pi}{2}$ iff all $x_i$'s are equal to $1$. So the answer in 2. is $2n$. Also the answer in 3. is $2n(2n-1)$ because you have $(2n)^2$ pairs of $(i,j)$ with $2n$ of them with equal coordinates. For 4. you should note that $\cos^{-1}x\leq \pi$, hence all summand must be equal to $\pi$, i.e. all $x_i$'s are equal to $-1$. Now the sum alternates: $-1+1-1+1-\ldots$ and is equal to $-1$ for odd $n$ and $0$ for even $n$.

Comment: Could you explain question 3 a bit more? @SMM
I understand question 4 now.

Comment: For question $2$ of your book, the anwser should be $2n$.

Comment: This sum, as it is written, is over all pairs $(i,j)$ such that $1\leq i,j\leq 2n$ and $i\neq j$. Since you have $2n$ choices for both $i$ and $j$, you have $(2n)^2$ pairs $(i,j)$ such that $1\leq i,j\leq 2n$. Among these pairs you have $2n$ of them such that $i=j$. So you have $(2n)^2-2n=2n(2n-1)$ pairs satisfying the condition of summation. And each summand is $1$, so the sum is equal to $2n(2n-1)$.

Comment: For question $3$ of your book the sum should be $n(n-1)=\frac{2n(n-1)}{2}$ , as it counts double every factor $x_{i}x_{j}$

Comment: Sounds good. Thank you. @SMM

Answer (score 1):

All three questions are based on the same concept of maximum value of $\arcsin x$ and $\arccos x$ which are $\pi/2$ and $\pi$.

In three, for example, the maximum value of left side can be $n\pi$ which is in right side, hence all $x_1,x_2,\cdots$ are $1$.